# Compositor options greyed out

Tags: compositing-nodes

I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and scroll to add image and it isn't highlighted, in fact **all the options are greyed out**. Can anyone please help me understand why?

*I have reloaded with factory settings.*

Comment: I figured it out, I had to add a node and then I was able to add image. My issue now is I do not know how to rotate the image. The picture is a JPEG and Blender keeps loading them improperly, so I need to correct with rotation. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable *Use Nodes*:

[image: Mouse hovering on 'use Nodes' checkbox]

and make sure you are not on the *Material Node Editor*, but on the *Compositor*:

[image]